# accumalator in reduce function either empty or not having the array data

Tags: javascript, reduce

Followin  is the array which i wanna reduce

```
          [{
            "CIs": {
              "CIs": {
                "x1": false,
                "x2": true,
                "x5": false,
                "x3": true,
                "x4": true,
              },
              "Username": "dev1"
            }
          },

          ​
          {
            "CIs": {
              "CIs": {
                "x3": true,
                "x2": true,
                "x1": false,
                "x4": true,
                "x5": true
              },
              "Username": "dev1"
            }
          },,

          ​
          {
            "CIs": {
              "CIs": {
                "x3": true,
                "x2": true,
                "x1": false,
                "x4": true,
                "x5": true
              },
              "Username": "dev2"
            }
          }

          ]
```

Here we c the "Username:dev1" that twice (these objects can be N no. of times) which I wanna reduce to the

i.e., resultant array

```
           [{
            "CIs": {
              "CIs": {
                "x3": true,
                "x2": true,
                "x1": false,
                "x4": true,
                "x5": true
              },
              "Username": "dev1"
            }
          },,

          ​
          {
            "CIs": {
              "CIs": {
                "x3": true,
                "x2": true,
                "x1": false,
                "x4": true,
                "x5": true
              },
              "Username": "dev2"
            }
          }

          ]
```

the issue is when I use reduce function and console "acc" then

Case 1: // there the acc is [] empty array

```
 reduceRes=upl.reduce(function(acc,d){
   console.log("acc,d",acc,d)
  //some logic here
   return acc;},[])}
```

Case 2: // there the acc is first object i.e., "{ "CIs": { "CIs": { "x1": false, "x2": true, "x5": false, "x3": true, "x4": true, }, "Username": "dev1" }"

```
 reduceRes=upl.reduce(function(acc,d){
   console.log("acc,d",acc,d)
  //some logic here
   return acc;})}
```

"acc" must be an array of 3 objects

I'm not following as to why "acc" is not an array of 3 objects

Can anyone lemme know as to where I'm going wrong

Comment: The second argument to `.reduce()` is the initial value of the accumulator. So `.reduce(function(acc,d){...},[])` sets the initial value to an empty array. Without that argument, the initial value of the accumulator is the first element of the array.

Comment: Also, the `CIs.x5` for the `dev1` username is not identical. The records are not duplicates.

Comment: Beyond those two things, you've provided no insight into what the `//some logic here` is that is producing the results you see. It is _that_ code that you've not included that is reducing to the result - we need to see that code.

Comment: See the [documentation for `reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Comment: @RandyCasburn  for Case 2 too acc has just 1obj no the array of obj from documentation i find it the array we wanna reduce to

Comment: that's because the first time through it sets `acc` to the first element and your provided code returns `acc` (or the first element). Each iteration after, `acc` is not modified in any way, so `acc` is returned and is still the first element from the array.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I'm checking duplicacy wrt Username , if there are N such (eg UserName:dev1) records the last will be the only record in the result array set

Comment: As I said previously, you have not provided the code that actually produces any result. Without seeing that code, there is no way to determine what is actually happening. I'm voting to close this question because it lacks debugging details.

Comment: @RandyCasburn //some logic here here im checking if `a.CI.Username===d.CI.Username`  using this logic to push to the acc

Comment: I've attempted to help you. But for some reason you continue to evade and deflect. For instance, there is no variable `a` in the code you provided, and there is no key within the object of `CI`. Edit your question with details. Perhaps someone will come along and help you. Good luck.

Comment: @RandyCasburn apologize //some logic here here im checking if acc.CI.Username===d.CI.Username using this logic to push to the acc   I'm working on it to acheive the result